# linux: mount old ATA disk to USB adapter

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, usb-storage

I am trying to recover data from an old Linux that was installed in a computer on an ATA hard drive. I found a ScanLogic Corp. SL11R-IDE IDE Bridge (04ce:0002), an ATA adapter to USB 1.0 like the one in the picture:

[image]
and after switching it on, I plugged it into a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. I am used to the drives being automatically mounted, but this one doesn't show up in /media. After doing a dmesg, all I got is this:

```
[  175.531463] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  175.626505] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04ce, idProduct=0002
[  175.626510] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  175.626515] usb 2-1.3: Product: ScanLogic USBIDE
[  175.626518] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: ScanLogic USBIDE
[  175.627314] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[  176.700616] usb 2-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  176.876168] usb 2-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  177.051668] usb 2-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  177.227343] usb 2-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
```

I tried plugging in the adapter to the three different USB ports in my laptop (one of them USB 3.0), but got no luck with any of them. I get different devices under, for example: `/dev/bus/usb/003/002` or `/dev/bus/usb/002/004`, but I don't get any `/dev/sdbN` links. The output `blkid -o list -c /dev/null` is just the laptop's partitions.

I have tried taking out the jumper, putting it as master and as CS Enabled, but didn't change the result.

If I plug it into a Windows7 laptop, the device is recognised but nothing is mounted. When I plug it into the Windows7 laptop and connect the device to a VMWare Ubuntu 12.04 session running on Windows7, I get the same results as with the Ubuntu laptop -- the `dmesg` results as above, but it is not mounted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not all (or even most?) USB devices do not completely follow the USB standard. I would open the case, check which USB to PATA chip is used and google for quirks with that chip.

Comment: Any Windows machine nearby? (Or you can use VMWare. Plug the drive into a Windows host, and use a Linux guest to save your data.)

Comment: totally OT, but what are those two rca style connectors for?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I have no idea either...

Comment: @Shiki when I plug it into a Windows7 laptop, the device is recognised but nothing is mounted. When I plug it and attach it to a VMWare Ubuntu 12.04 session, I get the same results as with the Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: Is the enclosure intended or big enough for a 5.25" half-height drive, e.g. a CD drive?  Then the two RCA phono jacks would be for stereo analog audio output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am used to the drives being automatically mounted

I thought so too.  But when I attached an old SATA drive using an external USB adapter last week, only the Windows NTFS partition was auto mounted.  I had to *manually* mount the *ext3* partitions, e.g.

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc5 /mnt
```

If you don't don't remember the partition numbers and filesystem types, you'll have to inspect the HDD with something like *gparted*. (The *ext3* and *sdc5* are examples that probably are not suitable for your drive.)

Comment: When I plug it into different USB ports, I get different devices under, for example: `/dev/bus/usb/003/002` or `/dev/bus/usb/002/004`, but I don't get any `/dev/sdbN` links.